# Subdomain/CNAME not working?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record

I'm trying to add streamlined parallel HTTP requests for my site, from what I read here:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-cnames-to-get-around-browser-connection-limits

However, I can't seem to get it to work.

I want:
http://dynamic0.vilegaming.com/layout/include/terran-img/h3.jpg

To point to:
http://vilegaming.com/layout/include/terran-img/h3.jpg

Here's what I have in my DNS..

```
dynamic0 CNAME vilegaming.com. 
dynamic1 CNAME 67.222.12.238 
dynamic2 CNAME ns1.vilegaming.com.
```

(0 and 2 point to the default Apache "working" page, and 1 says the site doesn't load.)

And in my httpd.conf..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName vilegaming.com
   ServerAlias *.vilegaming.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I hope your httpd.conf has more in it than that.  Can you post the full virtual host config please?

Comment: Here's all the VirtualHost lines: http://pastebin.com/f518d14a7

Comment: Why all the - votes for the question? All the information has been provided, it's clear english and well asked...

Answer (score 7):

Try changing dynamic1 to an A record instead of a CNAME.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for somewhat fixing it. Now it points to the Apache page like the other subdomains.

Comment: Another option is to change `67.222.12.238` to just `.` - as it is now it's looking for `67.222.12.238.vilegaming.com`, putting it to just `.` will "copy" the A record from `vilegaming.com`

Comment: @Farseeker - no a CNAME value of '.' will _not_ make it a copy of the previous record.

Answer (score 3):

CNAME needs to point to a hostname, not a nameserver and not an ip address.  So that explains why your entry for dynamic1 wasn't working.

As for why the other two entries aren't working, that's an Apache issue.  Vilegaming.com isn't set up in the config file you pointed to, at least not properly.  You need to find where it is set up and add the ServerAlias entry there.  Note that www.vilegaming.com also doesn't work, so you also need to add that in as a ServerAlias.  Try grepping /etc/apache2 for vilegaming.com to find out where it is configured.